# iOS Webview share app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an iOS Webview application written with no story boards how can I embed the sharing function on Webview button click

html code in website : Share Application

and I want to do this :

```
NSString *textToShare = @"Look at this awesome website for aspiring iOS Developers!";
    NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.codingexplorer.com/"];

    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                   UIActivityTypePrint,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want the url of links clicked by user then find it in this way

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
     //CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK. 
     NSLog(@"navigationType = %@",navigationType);

     return YES;
}
```